# Find the highest graded student in each state, using Relational Algebra

Tags: relational-theory, relational-algebra

Suppose I have a table of students, containing their ID, grade and state:

```
-------------------------
| id  |  grade  | state |
------------------------
|  1  |    83   |   CA  |
|  2  |    94   |   TX  |
|  3  |    92   |   WA  |
|  4  |    78   |   CA  |
```

And I want the ID of the students in *each* state with the highest grade (ex. 1, 2 and 3), how would I go about doing that?

I know how to find the maximum (can do the cross product (renaming as R1 and R2) and then select R1.grade < R2.grade for those who aren't the top, and subtract that from the original database). But I'm confused at how to do that for each state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll do it first using standard SQL and then use a tool called [RelaX--relational algebra calculator 0.18.2](http://dbis-uibk.github.io/relax/calc.htm) to do the translation.

Define and fill the table:

```
CREATE TABLE students
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    grade INTEGER,
    state TEXT
) ;

INSERT INTO students
    (id, grade, state)
VALUES
    (1, 83, 'CA'),
    (2, 94, 'TX'),
    (3, 92, 'WA'),
    (4, 78, 'CA') ;
```

RelaX will translate this into a dataset, represented by the following tuples:

```
students = {
    id:number, grade:number, state:string
    1        , 83          , 'CA'        
    2        , 94          , 'TX'        
    3        , 92          , 'WA'        
    4        , 78          , 'CA'        
}
```

We first need a table with tuples in the form `(state, grade)` having the maximum grade of each state. This is done in SQL with a `MAX(grade)` per `state` using a `GROUP BY state`:

```
SELECT
    state, max(grade) AS grade
FROM 
    students AS s2 
GROUP BY
    state ;
```

Next, you need to `JOIN` this table (that is named `max_grades`) to `students`, `ON` equal states and equal grades (i.e. the max grade per state).

```
SELECT
    s1.id
FROM
    students AS s1
    JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            state, max(grade) AS grade
        FROM 
            students
        GROUP BY
            state
    ) AS max_grades 
    ON s1.state = max_grades.state AND s1.grade = max_grades.grade
```

This gets translated by RelaX to the following relational algebra expression and response:

```
π s1.id
        ρ s1 students
    ⨝ s1.state = max_grades.state and s1.grade = max_grades.grade
        ρ max_grades (
            π state, grade
                γ state; MAX(grade)→grade ρ s2 students)
```

```
    s1.id  
    1  
    2  
    3
```

[image]

If several students of one state would have the max grade, this expression would return ALL of them, not just an arbitrary one of that state.

If you cannot `GROUP BY`, you can use another construct:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    id
FROM
    students
EXCEPT
SELECT
    s1.id
FROM
    students AS s1
    JOIN students AS s2 ON s1.state = s2.state AND s1.grade < s2.grade
```

This goes a bit more in-line with your original thinking, although I find it less clear.
The translation to relational algebra is:

```
    π id students
-   π s1.id
            ρ s1 students
        ⨝ s1.state = s2.state and s1.grade < s2.grade
            ρ s2 students
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In SQL: Using a derived table works. Let's call your table 'Students':

```
SELECT id
FROM Students
JOIN
  (SELECT State, Max(Grade) AS MaxGrade 
   FROM Students 
   GROUP BY State
  ) AS T 
ON T.State=Students.State  
WHERE Students.Grade >= T.MaxGrade;
```